# Linux - Internet Enabled Causes Entire Computer to Slow Until Reboot

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, drivers

Here are a few prerequisites. I am running Linux 4.4.0-21-generic on Linux Mint 18 Sarah x64. Everytime my internet is enabled it causes the internet to lag the entire computer until a reboot. This happens with every linux distro installed. Arch, Ubuntu, Mint. All the same. This only happens when turning on the PC after being shutdown. BTW I dual boot Windows 10 and Linux. This also happens when plugged in via ethernet. Again, tested on a fresh install from all three Distros. Again, the internet doesn't slow, just the entire PC.

```
Turns on PC after being shutdown.
Loads Linux
Horrible Lag
Reboot
Lag is Gone, internet is fine.
```

I am running a Toshiba Laptop with AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics 7000.

Update: I reformatted and installed via EUFI instead of legacy and performance is slightly better. After some googling I think it may be an IO problem. I look at IOtop and I'm getting 0 read and write with nothing using io. I'm thoroughly stumped. It only happens when dual booting windows. Without windows it works like a star.

Here is my top info

```
daltz3@daltzdev ~ $ top -b -n1 -o %CPU | head -20
top - 18:44:27 up 52 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.31, 0.32, 0.29
Tasks: 164 total,   1 running, 163 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 19.8 us,  6.6 sy,  1.1 ni, 72.0 id,  0.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7628224 total,  6208344 free,   681448 used,   738432 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 20481020 total, 20481020 free,        0 used.  6849736 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4367 daltz3    20   0   41800   3808   3268 R  22.2  0.0   0:00.07 top
 1893 daltz3    20   0 1307324 148452  67920 S  16.7  1.9   3:24.17 cinnamon
    1 root      20   0  120096   6272   3992 S   0.0  0.1   0:03.87 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.38 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:10.49 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.31 migration/0
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.72 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.70 ksoftirqd/1
daltz3@daltzdev ~ $
```

Comment: @roaima I use both Ethernet and wireless and it has the same effect and when I reboot it brings into grub where I select my Linux installation.

Comment: @roaima Added top on question.

Comment: Your system was running slow at the time you executed that `top` command? There's nothing obviously wrong there. In hindsight I think that a slightly different command would have provided more detail - `top -b -n1 -o %CPU | head -20` - so if you fancy replacing your first `top` output with the result from this one that might be beneficial.

Comment: @roaima Yes. My system was slow at the time of running the command. The top results will be replaced in about 8 minutes.

Comment: @roaima Replaced. Also might be useful to note that this effects response speed too. If I type a command using the Ctrl Alt F2 mode it takes slightly longer to respond than usual.

Comment: Very strange indeed. There is nothing there to suggest any sort of slow-down. At least, not within the OS. The load average is low. The system isn't swapping. It's 72% idle. Seeing as `cinnamon` has used a over 3 hours CPU time in the 52 minutes the system has been running I assume you've a multi-core system.

Comment: @roaima Yes it is a multi-core system. What I have been suspecting is that it has to be because I'm Dual booting but I have no way to make sure.

Comment: Dual booting should make no difference. If you leave your system running for an hour or so does the lag go away? Or does it only vanish when you boot into Linux the second time?

Comment: @roaima I wouldn't say it goes away more like It decreases quite a bit. Rebooting is the only real fix for the lag.

Comment: Re the `dmesg` output: you're suspending (sleeping) rather than shutting down...?

Comment: @roaima I shut down. I haven't suspended at all. I shutdown and all the lights go off and it brings me to the grub menu once I turn t back on

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar with a misconfigured iptables, but I recommend booting a live usb, or clean install, then configure untill you fined the problem causing step... maybe your kernel is not reserving enough space for itself...dmesg output might be informative.

Comment: How would I configure it, and I have booted into a live CD and it runs with less lag then when I haven rebooted. How would I fix this without deleting my windows partition as I have important data on it.

Comment: Here is my dmesg output. I used pastebin because it said the output was too long. http://pastebin.com/NjcAPfQm

Comment: So I wiped my hard-drive and installed Linux mint first (previously I installed Windows first) and it ran flawlessly. Then I installed Windows 10 alongside it and the same problem repeats. What the heck?